# Using Facebook SDK ShareDialog to share message and photo

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK for Android, because I want allow users to share an image generated in the app + a message which I would like to set already as suggestion.

I tried using the new `ShareDialog`, but somehow I cannot find a way to share a photo and a message. The `FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder` lets you share photos from the device, but not a message, whereas the `FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder` lets you only share a link.

What can I use instead? Should I move away from using the share dialog?

Comment: what message would that be? just let the user fill it in, it must be 100% user generated anyway.

Comment: As @luschn mentioned, the message must be user generated, and prefilling it would violate Facebook Platform Policy. This is why the share dialogs don't have a field for you to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create alert dialog and edittext within it, then you can allow user to the add their comment.

For the image , you can get the image path for the file storage and load it as a Bitmap.

Then create a bundle with above comment and image and send a post Request to the fb API with the validated and opened session.